# SoapUI property transfer, using result to look up values

Tags: rest, groovy, properties, soapui

I'm trying to do a property transfer with SoapUI with a groovy script for a Json response. However, I'm not too familiar with groovy so I'm not having any luck.

What I'm trying to do is the following. I want to set the values corresponding to the output for the three digits below, "digit1", "digit2" and "digit3". So I should have three variables with the values "digit1totransfer" = 2, "digit2totransfer" = 1, "digit3totransfer" = 4.

**Response**

```
{
       "ApiSuccess": true,
       "Data":    {
          "LogOnResult": 1,
          "Token": "1",
          "LogOnStep1Result":       {
             "Digit1": 2,
             "Digit2": 1,
             "Digit3": 4
          }
       },
       "SessionId": ""
    }
```

I then want to use the "digit1totransfer" (so in this case 2) to look up a different values from a known list. The values that for the lookup are [9,8,7,6,5,4]. And then save that looked up value. So I should have a variable called "outputDigit1" with a value of 8. This will be repeated for "digit2totransfer" and "digit3totransfer" with a separate output variable for each.

I then want to transfer these "outputdigit1", "outputdigit2" and "outputdigit3" into a request, the input to the request are called "code1", "code2" and code "code3". See request below.

```
{
"code1": 8,
"code2": 9,
"code3": 6
}
```

Comment: It is not clear from your question, what are you trying to achieve? do you want to extract any data from above json? or you want to set some data to this json? Please use edit option to update the details in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. What do you mean by `My list is 6 digits long`?

Comment: Can please you show the final output(by replacing the values from your list that you are talking) of the request instead of `outputdigit1` etc.,?